# Schema.org markup for B2B organization

Tags: schema.org

My question is about adding Schema.org markup for a B2B website, wherein *X* is the parent company and *Y* is an entity of the parent company.

Since we cannot add an `Organization` markup to *Y* which is an entity, what other Schema.org markup would be applicable to *Y*?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use Organization for Y and specifiy the relationship between X and Y using the departement property of Organization ( in Y).

https://schema.org/Organization
https://schema.org/department

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Let me check if this works.

Answer (score 0):

To relate two [`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization) (or sub-types of `Organization`) entities, these are the possible properties (as of [version 2.2](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.2)):

- [`brand`](http://schema.org/brand)
- [`department`](http://schema.org/department)
- [`member`](http://schema.org/member) / [`memberOf`](http://schema.org/memberOf)
- [`parentOrganization`](http://schema.org/parentOrganization) / [`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization)

According to your description, `parentOrganization` (or the inverse `subOrganization`) seem to be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well I am still trying to find a workaround for this. What if Y is the product of X and Y has a separate domain altogether. Will the brand markup be applicable for Y? or only the product markup would specify brand/organization as X and product type as Y...

Comment: @KiethRichards: Well, if *Y* is a product, the property [`owns`](http://schema.org/owns) might apply. Or `brand`, if you consider it to be a brand. (Both from the perspective of the `Organization`.)