# Schema for e-commerce website that also has store

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm adding Schema.org in JSON-LD format to an e-commerce website that sells furniture all over the USA, and also has a furniture showroom where people can go see and buy furniture.

I was happy to see there is a type [`FurnitureStore`](http://schema.org/FurnitureStore) which is a perfect fit. The problem is `FurnitureStore` is a subset of `Store` which is a subset of `LocalBusiness`. Our SEO consultant thinks `LocalBusiness` isn't the right type for an online business that has a national scope. He says we should instead use `Organization`.

The data is currently structured like this:

```json
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "FurnitureStore",
"@id": "url#hook",
"name": "Name",
"image": "image path",
"address": {
  "@type": "PostalAddress",
  "addressLocality": "",
  "addressRegion": "",
  "postalCode":"",
  "streetAddress": ""
},
"description": "",
"telephone": "",
"currenciesAccepted": "USD",
"openingHours": ["", "", ""]
```

I'm seeing similar online stores either using `Organization`, `WebSite`, `Store` and sometimes nothing.

What Schema.org type best fits this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an `Organization` and a `FurnitureStore` item and connect them with the [`parentOrganization`](http://schema.org/parentOrganization)/[`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization) properties:

```json
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Organization",
"subOrganization": {
  "@type": "FurnitureStore",
  "address": {},
  "openingHoursSpecification": {}
}
```

(There are [other properties to connect `Organization` items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35506845/1591669), which might also apply in some contexts.)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the way to go. Given that most sales are online, should I also add a "@type" : "Website" to the node?

Comment: @jolly-green-giant: Good question. I’m not sure. Ideally Schema.org would offer a type for web shops, but they don’t. On a hunch, I would not multi-type, but add the `WebSite` via [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) to the `Organization`.

Answer (score 1):

You or your SEO consultant should think about benefits of structured data first. I mean, forget about consultants - just answer the question: "Why do you add structured data to your page?".

I am talking about the reason. When I hear about the perfect fit for national business, etc. - I always propose to read [Structured Data Introduction by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data). Yes, they say that you will help to understand the content, etc. BUT then you can read that SD doesn't influence on your ranking. This means that you have only able to improve how does your page look in the search engine result pages (SERP) by snippets.

There is a list of snippets (SERP view improvements or "search results feature") that each search engine supports. There are two main systems we use: mostly [Google](https://www.google.com) and [Bing](https://www.bing.com) / [Yahoo](https://www.yahoo.com).

Here are two main links you need to go through:

- [Google's snippets/improvements](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery)
- [Bing's information about additional marking up your data](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/marking-up-your-site-with-structured-data-3a93e731)

Just to go from theories. Let's go over an example with one of the snippets: use "Product" as you're going to sell something in your store. I was searching for lab test before reading your question here. So, it is still open, and I just did a screenshot of the part of it.

[image: A1c test cost - Google]

I went through few of them and got the one I liked with pricing comparison of [A1c Test](https://www.findlabtest.com/lab-test/general-health-panel/a1c-test-cost-quest-496). Please [check markup in Google's SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.findlabtest.com%2Flab-test%2Fgeneral-health-panel%2Fa1c-test-cost-quest-496):

[image: Google's SDTT screenshot]

I guess that going through the google's link will give you the exact list of items to use. As for my opinion, you will need [Organization](http://schema.org/Organization) - to provide details about you on the first page, for instance. Also, you will need [Product](http://schema.org/Product) schemas on pages where a user sees info about furniture. If you need something more - do it. 
However, please don't play with fake stars in ratings - Google bans for this ;)

P.s. if you see some cool snippet from a competitor - do not hesitate to use structured data testing tools to check how to do the same ;)